# Wicket: How to pass model changes to parent components? onModelChanged() doesn't work

Tags: model, wicket, onchange, event-bubbling

I have a component containing a form with many TextFields.
The way it should work is that when changed, the value should be persisted immediately (no Save button, all through AJAX).

The AJAX calls work fine, the value gets to the model.

The code to save the model (and the entity contained) is in the parent component.
I thought I would override onModelChanged() to propagate the changes from the components to the parent.
But onModelChanged() is not called.

Parent has its own model as class member field.
The subcomponents use this:

```
ReleaseTraitRowPanel( String id, IModel<IHasTraits> relModel, ... ) {
    ...
    PropertyModel<String> traitModel = new PropertyModel( relModel.getObject().getTraits(), prop);

    EditableLink4 link = new EditableLink4("link", traitModel){
        // Pass the change notification to upper level. TODO: Does Wicket do this automatically?
        @Override protected void onModelChanged() {
            ReleaseTraitRowPanel.this.onModelChanged();
        }
    };
    ...

}
```

How should it be done?
Should I pass the onModelChanged() at all? Or does wicket have some way to notify the other model of changes?

Related - is CompoundPropertyModel only for forms, or can I use it with any component? I could use it here - `prop` is the same as id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The problem was that I had a Validator which always failed, and `onModelChanged()` is called after the validation passes. And the validation error message didn't get to FeedbackPanel since it didn't get added to `AjaxRequestTarget`...

After all this is done, osdamv's answer also applies.
I wrote a blog post about that.
https://community.jboss.org/people/ozizka/blog/2013/01/21/wicket-creating-ajax-enabled-entity-based-pages

Answer (score 1):

you are using the wrong method, you should use modelChanged(), if you look his source code is something like this

```
/**
 * Called to indicate that the model content for this component has been changed
 */
public final void modelChanged()
{
    // Call user code
    internalOnModelChanged();
    onModelChanged();
}
```

in the other hand onModelChanged() is

```
/**
 * Called anytime a model is changed after the change has occurred
 */
protected void onModelChanged()
{
}
```

as you can see  onModelChanged() is a call for modelChanged().

CompoundPropertyModel can be used in any WebMarkUpContainer; in others words, in almost every container